# interaction Django and Ajax

Tags: django, jquery

I'm trying to send data to the server and use with AJAX

```
function stats(e){
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"stats",
    data:{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
'test':{}},
success: function(data) {alert("Congratulations!"+data);},
error: function(data) {
alert("Please report this error: "+data.responseText);}
});
}
```

function in views.py:

```
def stats(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.POST:
                return HttpResponse(request.POST['test'])
            else:
                return HttpResponse("post_no_exists") 
        else:
            return HttpResponse("no authenticate")
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Django raise MultiValueDictKeyError 'key "test" not found in QueryDict'.
When I change "test":{} -> "test":1 it succeds. 
Whats my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
...
data: {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ...,
    'test': {}
}
...
```

You're trying to send an empty object literal as part of the POST request. jQuery can't figure out what value to send for that (empty object? what would that even mean?), so it simply doesn't send the `test` parameter at all. Thus, on the server side, trying to access `request.POST['test']` throws a KeyError.

When you change the test to a different literal (in this case a number), jQuery can easily encode and send that as the value.

Comment: Why if i write "test":{"a":1}, request.POST['test'] raise error, but request.POST['test[a]'] gives 1 ?

Comment: @user2661362: Because jQuery sends that request as the key-value pair `"test[a]": 1`. POST parameters do not support any nested data structure, so jQuery "unpacks" them.

Answer (score 0):

You need return answer as json

```
payload = {'answer': 'post_no_exists'}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload, cls=LazyEncoder), content_type='application/json')
```

in js

```
alert("Congratulations!"+data.answer);
```